# repeat data to get retention rate

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, retention

I want to create retention rate, but I have one problem to face, how to repeat the 0 date to make some divide.

I have the data look like this

```
week_monday    users     week_diff
2021-11-01     560       0
2021-11-01     340       1
2021-11-08     600       0
2021-11-08     100       1
2021-11-08      60       2
2021-11-08      40       3
```

what I want is repeating the 0 week_diff to every group date, so I can divide it to get the retention rate

```
week_monday    users     week_diff   users_2   retention_rate
2021-11-01     560       0           560       1
2021-11-01     340       1           560       0.6
2021-11-08     600       0           600       1
2021-11-08     100       1           600       0.16
2021-11-08      60       2           600       0.1
2021-11-08      40       3           600       0.06
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
SELECT week_monday, users, week_diff,
    MAX (users) OVER (PARTITION BY week_monday) AS users_2,
    users / max(users) OVER (PARTITION BY week_monday) AS retention_rate
FROM mydataset.mytable
ORDER BY week_monday, week_diff
```

Output:

[image]